# Unable to authenitcate with python minds api

Tags: python, json, authentication, python-requests, jwt

I'm trying to access the social site, minds.com via [this python api](https://gitlab.com/granitosaurus/minds-api) by by installing the module locally with `python3 setup.py install && pipenv run python` and following the instructions to log in.

However, I get this error message when trying to authenticate:

(For some reason, Stackoverflow doesn't allow me to post the python error-log becuse it isn't indented properly, so here it is https://pastebin.com/0sWa1hmY)

The code, which seems to be called from the python api looks like this:

[minds/api.py](https://gitlab.com/granitosaurus/minds-api/blob/master/minds/api.py)

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from pprint import pprint

from requests.utils import dict_from_cookiejar, cookiejar_from_dict

from minds.connections import XSRFSession
from minds.exceptions import AuthenticationError
from minds.profile import Profile
from minds.utils import add_url_kwargs
from minds.endpoints import *
from minds.sections import NewsfeedAPI, ChannelAPI, NotificationsAPI, 
PostingAPI, InteractAPI


class Minds(NewsfeedAPI, ChannelAPI, NotificationsAPI, PostingAPI, ...):
    _xsrf_retries = 5

    def __init__(self, profile: Profile = None, login=True):
        self.con = XSRFSession()
        self.profile = profile
        if self.profile:
            if profile.cookie:
                self.con.cookies = cookiejar_from_dict(profile.cookie)
            if profile.proxy:
                self.con.proxies = {'https': profile.proxy, 'http':\
                profile.proxy}
        self._establish_xsrf()
        if self.profile and login and not self.is_authenticated:
            if profile.username and profile.password:
                self.authenticate(profile.username, profile.password)

(...)

def authenticate(self, username, password, save_profile=True) -> dict:
    """
    Authenticate current instance with given user
    :param: save_profile: whether to save profile locally
    """
    auth = {
        'username': username,
        'password': password
    }
    resp = self.con.post(AUTHENTICATE_URL, json=auth)
    self.user = resp.json()
    if self.user['status'] == 'failed':
        raise AuthenticationError("Couldn't log in with the ...")
    self.guid = self.user['user']['guid']
    if save_profile:
        Profile(
            username=username,
            password=password,
            cookie=self.get_cookies(),
            proxy=self.con.proxies.get('https'),
        ).save()
    return resp.json()
```

The python API doesn't seem to be maintained, but I think minds.com newly uses jsonwebtokens for authentication. Is the something missing from the api to be jwt-enabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After compare to browser request again and again. The reason why occurred error is you gave a wrong content-type, but actually you need to send as json data (it seems website is making joke). So you  need to specify `headers["content-type"] = "text/plain"`. Otherwise website will response 500.

Note: To avoid broad discussion, i can only answer this error.

Change the code to below, but there is only one line differs from source code :).

```
def authenticate(self, username, password, save_profile=True) -> dict:
    """
    Authenticate current instance with given user
    :param: save_profile: whether to save profile locally
    """
    auth = {
        'username': username,
        'password': password
    }
    self.con.headers["content-type"] = "text/plain" ####
    resp = self.con.post(AUTHENTICATE_URL, json=auth)
    self.user = resp.json()
    if self.user['status'] == 'failed':
        raise AuthenticationError("Couldn't log in with the given credentials")
    self.guid = self.user['user']['guid']
    if save_profile:
        Profile(
            username=username,
            password=password,
            cookie=self.get_cookies(),
            proxy=self.con.proxies.get('https'),
        ).save()
    return resp.json()
```